# Having trouble including boost binary_oarchive.hpp

Tags: c++, boost

I have boost installed and I am trying to use boost oarchive in my C++ program

I have binary_oarchive included at the top

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
```

But I guess a multitude of undefined reference errors such as these.

```
/tmp/ccqt0MAu.o: In function `boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::~common_oarchive()':
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:35: undefined reference to `boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::~basic_oarchive()'
/tmp/ccqt0MAu.o: In function `boost::archive::binary_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::~binary_oarchive_impl()':
/usr/include/boost/archive/binary_oarchive_impl.hpp:34: undefined reference to `boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_binary_oprimitive()'
```

I was wondering what we I could be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are linker errors and indicate that you aren't linking to the boost serialization library. The command to do this varies based on your platform, but it could be `-lboost_serialization`.